# Is it recommended to start Playframework 1.x application?

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-1.x

`Playframework 2.0` is our there but I think most current `app servers` will not be able to support ([as It will require `Servlet 3.1`](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8-war-packaging)).

I need to **start a new Play app** but don't know if `Play1.0` will still maintained so that I could create the new app using it ...

thoughts please .... alternatives  ...

Answer (score 2):

Starting a new application with Play 1.X is perfectly fine, although I would recommend that you use the current version (1.2.4 at this moment) instead of 1.0.

Play 1.X is still very much alive. For example, the latest release candidate vor version 1.2.5 came out two weeks ago (May 29).
[Here are some comments](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1494-add-faqs-about-future-play-1x-plans) by Peter Hilton, a Play developer, regarding the future of Play 1.X.

Also, you might be interested in [this article](http://blog.awfbeat.com/post/22314115684/impressions-of-play-framework-1-2-4-vs-2-0), which compares the pros and cons of Play 1.X and 2.0.

So, in conclusion: Don't worry. Start your new project with Play 1.2.4. Everything will be fine. :)

Comment: If you plan to switch later I suggest you start with scala templates right away